# Dotliquid: value from string

Tags: string, dotliquid

Is there a way to get the value from a string?

For example:

```
"SomeString" has the value "Edward".
```

Input:

```liquid
{% assign variable = 'SomeString' %}

{{ variable }}
```

Output:

```
SomeString
```

**Note**: `SomeString` is a constructed string during runtime, so I in fact need to get the value from a string --> I can't remove the quotes in the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in DotLiquid which allows to do that, however it is always possible to create your own `Tag` or to build the template at run time.

```cs
public sealed class RuntimeAssign : Tag
{
     ...
}


Template.RegisterTag<RuntimeAssign>("runtimeassign");
```